# Faye Server as daemon or automatically started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin, faye

I want to use Faye on production server on my VPS. how can I start faye server automatically or as a daemon process.

Because when I start faye server using SSH it shutdown as i close ssh connection. Please guide me its really urgent.

I am using Rails 3.1.rc1

Answer (score 2):

I use faye as my message server currently. 
Perhaps you would want to make faye as a daemon.
I use this for my faye app.

http://rubygems.org/gems/daemons

just

```
gem install daemons
```

and edit ur own rake file or a plain ruby to run daemon up. that's all

there are lots of daemon tools for ruby.

You can also combine faye with sinatra or thin,
but it's a little bit hassle when you can use daemons and fire it up in 3 mins. :)

Answer (score 0):

you might be interested in this [daemon-controller](https://github.com/FooBarWidget/daemon_controller).